# Javascript shortcut ... is it possible?

Tags: javascript

I have a class with just one property:

```
var A = function(b){this.Value=b};
var a = new A('hello world');
```

I would like to retrieve the value of the property as follows:

```
var what = a;   //instead of  using var what =a.Value;
```

Is it possible? In python I know that I can use **call** to implement it.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self,b):
        self.Value=b
    def __call__(self):
        return self.Value
 a=A('hello world')
 what=a()
```

Comment: To implement what? How would you expect to differentiate between evaluating a whole object and its part in any expression? With `call`, you have to write an object name with parenthesis.

Comment: Well, if you're ok with additional syntax, you can just implement `valueOf` function, then prepend your object names with `unary plus` operator each time you want to get their values instead. The question is, will someone but you (but not you 6 months later) understand this idea when reviewing the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

The best you can do is to define the `toString` method in the class prototype, so you can use the object directly in the strings:

```
A.prototype.toString = function() {return this.Value;};
var a = new A('hello world');

var str = 'The string is: ' + a;
```

Comment: Haven't voted on this, but using `valueOf` is way more semantic. Even though `toString` technically can return anything, it _should_ return a `String` value. `valueOf` is completely another story.

Comment: @raina77ow Yes, of course I agree with you, but see... What kurro wanted was a *shortcut* and, sadly, using `valueOf` isn't...

Comment: Tell me, how exactly `valueOf` can't be used in your example?

Comment: @raina77ow It can. But if you want a 'shortcut', you'd get it in strings, and so I think `toString` is sematically better in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. But it is an object. if you want to get the value of it you have to call `what.Value`